# Performing action on JComboBox - SwingUI

Tags: java, swing, combobox, actionlistener

I've implemented a ComboBox using NetBeans that has a list of values, I want to be able to perform an action whenever the selected index has changed. An example being when a user changes the current item from Item 1 to Item 2.

Comment: All you have to do is read the JComboBox API and you will find a link to the Swing tutorial on "How to Use Combo Boxes". The API is the first place to start.

Comment: Guess my search foo is off, thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a usage example from [*The Java Tutorials*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#listeners):

```
public class ComboBoxDemo ... implements ActionListener {
    . . .
        petList.addActionListener(this) {
    . . .
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
        String petName = (String)cb.getSelectedItem();
        updateLabel(petName);
    }
    . . .
}
```

**Edit:**

An `ActionListener` is

> The listener interface for receiving
>   action events. The class that is
>   interested in processing an action
>   event implements this interface, and
>   the object created with that class is
>   registered with a component, using the
>   component's addActionListener method.
>   When the action event occurs, that
>   object's actionPerformed method is
>   invoked.

**Edit 2:**

Here's another usage example to satisfy *kleopatra*, that is, one that is more exemplary of best practices:

```
JComboBox yourComboBox = new JComboBox();
yourComboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: Would you mind clarifying how the ActionListener works? Does it trigger through any interaction with the ComboBox or can you use the parameter passed into the actionPerformed method? To elaborate I've tested and noticed it works when I select a new item, can this be expanded if I wanted it to fire on a different event? Apologies, i'm used to the event handling of C#

Comment: Read the tutorial. The answer was posted 3 minutes ago. You could not possibly have read the tutorial, downloaded the example and tested it before asking for more information.

Comment: @Jamie: Sure, just register another [EventListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EventListener.html)

Comment: -1 for implementing the ActionListener on the demo itself (exposes public api that's not meant to be used). Instead _use_ an internal ActionListener

Comment: @kleopatra: seriously? this was taken _DIRECTLY_ from _The Java Tutorials_. if you have a problem with this answer, why not consult the persons who designed the example? sheesh...

Comment: they are immune to suggestions ;-) Anyway, they doing thingies wrong doesn't excuse any copied snippets not being filtered through best practices knowledge

Comment: @kleopatra: _sigh_ ... I suppose you're right :). that being said, I provided a better usage example. appreciate the criticism.